# Effectively Ending Storyboards via XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, memory-leaks, storyboard

Recently ran into the `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` on `EventTrigger` memory leak on some storyboards and while although I know how to fix it, I was wondering if there's any other quick-and-easy things I can do to help avoid the storyboard type leaks in the future? Such as just attaching a completed handler or something to make sure everything gets disposed properly?

I know it's a bit of an open question but looking to improve the process moving forward (for anything that would support storyboards SL/WPF, etc.) hopefully just with xaml so I'm not flipping around different places for every instance and can do it while I'm working in the storyboards themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to stop a `Storyboard` in XAML is to use the [`StopStoryboard` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... the opposite to the `BeginStoryboard` element. There are other `xxxStoryboard` classes too... from the linked page on MSDN:

```
  <StackPanel.Triggers>

    <!-- Begin the Storyboard -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="BeginButton">
      <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
        <Storyboard >
          <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
            Duration="0:0:5" From="100" To="500" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

    <!-- Pause the Storyboard -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="PauseButton">
      <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MyBeginStoryboard" />
    </EventTrigger>

    <!-- Resume the Storyboard -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="ResumeButton">
      <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MyBeginStoryboard" />
    </EventTrigger>

     <!-- Seek one second into the storyboard's active period. -->
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="SeekButton">
       <SeekStoryboard 
        BeginStoryboardName="MyBeginStoryboard" 
        Offset="0:0:1" Origin="BeginTime" />
    </EventTrigger>   

    <!-- Skip to Fill -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="SkipToFillButton">
      <SkipStoryboardToFill BeginStoryboardName="MyBeginStoryboard" />
    </EventTrigger>

    <!-- Stop the Storyboard -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="StopButton">
      <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MyBeginStoryboard" />
    </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: See that's where I guess I was running into the uncertainty of the operation of StopStoryboard, does it dispose of the process and the objects so everything pertaining to the storyboard is out of memory on completion? And can it be incorporate inline into the storyboard so the storyboard would run, and call the stop immediately after to ensure it indeed is a "stopped" and disposed?

Comment: PS - in case it helps what I'm currently doing to fix my current found debacle (should have got a good memory profiler much sooner) is moving  everything in statemanager's and ditching anything recursive like the endless repeats.

Comment: So looking over (the link of the page)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905(v=vs.110).aspx] ya copied the example from, it doesn't address the Memory leak from the association of 'RepeatBehavior="Forever"' and `EventTrigger` so I'm wondering if that's the only situation it's found in or if I could literally just limit it from Forever to something like `RepeatBehavior="50x"` and it clean up the leakage the same way while still keeping the EventTriggers and ControlStoryBoardAction calls in place? hmmm.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help with the memory leak part of your question.